# What does --prefix do exactly when used in ./configure?

Tags: configure

So I just had a simple question that's probably going to make me look dumb, but I'm learning

When I do a

```
./configure --prefix/usr/bin/
```

What is the prefix doing ? 
Is this just installing the package into that location

And can a reply give more of an elaborate answer for a complicated install and explain in detail the prefixes and options that go with it.

If I was to run an apt-get install  how would I install it to a certain location with prefix

I've also seen

```
 PREFIX=/tmp/installdir make


 PREFIX=/tmp/installdir make install
```

If prefix is called in ./configure why is it always being made in these two examples ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Some info here: [GNU Coding Standards: Directory Variables](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html)

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/config.htm ,this will help you more

Comment: Reviewers: This is about *installing software*. It has three *off-topic* close votes as "not about Ubuntu." If closing this is somehow consistent with [any](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) [actual](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/47/how-do-we-tell-if-a-question-belongs-here-or-rather-at-stackoverflow-superuser) [site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14523/are-not-only-ubuntu-specific-questions-on-topic) [policy](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14663/are-non-ubuntu-spefic-questions-allowed), I suggest commenting. Otherwise this will likely be reopened even if it's closed.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When you install software with `make install` or `sudo make install`, different files are placed in different directories. Executables that provide commands the user is intended to run usually go in a `bin` directory, libraries usually go in a `lib` directory, manual  pages usually go in a `man` directory, and so forth.

When you run `./configure`, **the `--prefix` option lets you specify where *those* directories are**. It is called `--prefix` because it lets you give the *prefix* that appears in the paths to each of the directories where files from the program or library that you are building are to be installed. Most `configure` scripts support `--prefix`, and omitting it and just running `./configure` is typically equivalent to `./configure --prefix=/usr/local`.

To answer this more fully, I've reproduced two sections from [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389905/11938) to [How to install tar file “globally”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389896/how-to-install-tar-file-globally) (on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)), which address this question specifically:

> #### Configuring Your Build
>
> When you have source code that is compiled by running `./configure`
>   and `make`, you will usually use `make install` (or `sudo make install`)
>   to install it. This copies files from the build directory
>   into the install location. When the thing you are installing provides
>   executable commands, those executables are typically copied into a
>   directory that is in `$PATH` or that you should consider adding to
>   `$PATH`.
>
> Although building and installing software is often as simple as
>   running `./configure`, `make`, sometimes `make check` or `make test`,
>   and then `make install` or `sudo make install`, you will sometimes
>   want to pass options to the `configure` script to configure the build.
>   In particular, [**as pfnuesel says**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389898/11938), this is how you configure
>   *where* the software is going to be installed. Even though the `make install` step actually installs the software, the locations where
>   everything will be installed are typically established in the
>   `./configure` step.
>
> The most common option for this is `--prefix`. The default prefix,
>   when you don't tell `configure` what to use, is usually `/usr/local`.
>   (Occasionally, a program or library's source code defaults to some
>   other prefix. Fortunately this is rare.)
>
> So `./configure` is usually equivalent to `./configure --prefix=/usr/local`.
>   To install software in your home directory, you could use `./configure --prefix=/home/galahad` (if `/home/galahad` is
>   your home directory) or `--prefix="$HOME"`. Then of course you must
>   still build and install the software with `make`. I should say that
>   not all software that is distributed in source code form is built this
>   way. You should always look for documentation inside the extracted
>   source code archive.
>
> #### What `--prefix` Means
>
> When you run `./configure --prefix=directory`, you are
>   indicating that the software should be installed under the
>   *`directory`* directory. But this rarely, if ever, places loose files in *`directory`*. Instead, it places files that serve different
>   purposes in the different subdirectories of *`directory`*. If those
>   subdirectories don't exist, it creates them.
>
> Executables usually go in `directory/bin`, though they
>   may go in `directory/sbin` if they're commonly used for
>   system administration or they may go (more rarely, these days) in
>   `directory/games` if they are games. Libraries go in
>   `directory/lib` or another similarly named directory like
>   `directory/lib32`. Header files go in
>   `directory/include`. Manual pages go in
>   `directory/man`. Data files used by the software go in
>   `directory/share`.
>
> That's what it means for *`directory`* to be a *prefix*. It's the
>   parent directory that contains the locations in which different files
>   will be installed. **It thus appears as a prefix** in the [absolute
>   paths](https://foldoc.org/absolute%20path) of most files and directories created by running `make install`
>   or `sudo make install`.
>
> There are some exceptions to this. Systemwide configuration
>   files--which are sometimes created when installing the software that
>   will use them, though not always--usually go in `/etc`. This is not
>   typically affected by specifying a different prefix. Even if you
>   install a lot of software in `/usr/local`, it will still mostly use
>   `/etc`, and your `/usr/local/etc` directory will probably be
>   nonexistent, empty, or contain very few files.
>
> On many systems, you can find more information about typical
>   filesystem layout by running `man hier`. If you're using a GNU/Linux
>   system you may be interested in the [Filesystem Hierarchy
>   Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Answer (score 2):

It tells the location of the things which are required to configure the current package or software.

Like in a simple case, it can tell the location of ssl libraries:

```
--with-libssh2=/usr/local  #used in configuring nagios
```

and it also tells which packages not to configure, to make suitable compilations of the program according to your system:

```
--disable-shared  # used in configuring nagios
--disable-link-balancer  # used in configuring Firehol
```

These are just extra options to make a compilation suitable for your system.
It is what I think. Do correct me if it is something else.

The `--prefix=PREFIX` option installs architecture independent files in `PREFIX`. When you run a `make install`command, libraries will be placed in the `PREFIX/lib` directory, executables in the `PREFIX/bin` directory and so on.

If this argument is not passed to the `configure` command then the default value is `/usr/local`.