# How do I use different Wine bottles?

Tags: wine, 32-bit, winetricks

I can't figure this out, I'm trying to run `winetricks` and install prerequisites needed for running 32-bit Windows software, but I don't even know how to begin to do that. Every time I open `winetricks` it opens as 64-bit `winetricks`. I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: What is the architecture of your system and what version of wine did you install?

Comment: 64-bit and I installed the latest stable version of WINE

Comment: Can you explain this "I'm trying to run winetricks and install stuff in a 32 bit"?

Comment: I'm trying to install dotnet20 in WINE using winetricks, and it doesn't do it without a 32-bit WINE prefix and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Then that should be the title of the question, as it explains it better

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I wrote the accepted answer to [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891835/what-does-prefix-do-exactly-when-used-in-configure), and I don't see how that question or either of its answers would be relevant to this. That's about the `--prefix` option to `./configure` scripts for compiling software. If you're thinking of `WINEPREFIX`, [we have this](https://askubuntu.com/a/231605/22949) (though [just setting `WINEARCH` may be sufficient](https://askubuntu.com/a/139254/22949)).